# How can I hide Google Documents from Finder?

Tags: finder

I have Google Drive installed on my MacBook and I can see all the Google format documents (i.e. gsheet, gdoc etc.). How can I hide these so that they don't appear in Finder?

For those asking for a screenshot please see below. Top image show my MacBook which shows the Google files. Bottom image is from my iMac which DOESN'T show the files - so it must be possible and I must have done it at some point but I have no idea how!

[image: Showing the issue]

Comment: Please add a screenshot.

Comment: If they are located all within a folder in Finder you could go to Terminal and change the folder flag so that the folder is hidden, is that what you are looking for? More info means more help ;)

Comment: I was about to ask this question again and noticed that it had already been asked by me! I still don't know how to prevent these from showing. They aren't real files but links to the documents on drive.google.com. I don't want to see them. Isn't anyone else frustrated by this?